# bash alias command with both single and double quotes

Tags: linux, bash, quotes, double-quotes

I have the following command:

```
svn status | awk '$1 =="M"{print $2;}'
```

How do I make an alias out of it? I have tried:

```
alias xx="svn status | awk '$1 ==\"M\"{print $2;}'"
```

Answer (score 161, accepted):

You just need to escape it correctly.

```
alias xxx="svn status | awk '\$1 ==\"M\"{print \$2;}'"
```

Comment: So I wasn't escaping the $.. didn't know that!

Comment: Nice! I didn't know I had to escape the '$' either!

Comment: Good answer but also a reminder how easy it is to make mistakes. In the case I was handling there were already escaped characters and it made a huge mess. EJK's answer below was more useful for me, a function is probably a cleaner option for many :)

Comment: @jeremyclarke I don't disagree, escaping is hard, avoid it if you can.

Comment: Does ` need to be escaped?

Comment: @AaronFranke Depends heavily on the context. Maybe you should create a new question? :)

Comment: @Shadoninja, the `$` needs to be escaped because those are double quotation marks

Answer (score 132):

Here's something that accomplishes the same thing without using an alias.  Put it in a function in your .bashrc:

```
xx() {
    svn status | awk '$1 =="M"{print $2;}'
}
```

This way you don't have to worry about getting the quotes just right.  This uses the exact same syntax you would at the command line.

Comment: +1, but one quibble -- the `function` keyword is a needless incompatibility with POSIX. Just leave it off: `xx() { ...`

Comment: This is simpler and I like it, but the other one answered the question  more precisely..

Comment: @pragmatic_programmer That's a fair interpretation. Personally, I still hold that this answer is the better one despite not being responsive in a literal sense -- at least 50% of the time we get questions about aliases in irc.freenode.org's `#bash`, the answer is "use a function instead"; aliases can do nothing but prefix expansion, which isn't useful if you want to, for instance, branch on arguments.

Comment: This is indeed the better answer (and easier to handle) answer.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I thoroughly agree this is the best answer, I've choosen the other just on fairness, but is not my interpretation, I asked how to quote an alias, he responded.. not an easy choice still! thanks

Comment: There are times when a literal answer to the exact question is much more preferred, but most of the time, an answer like this one is much more helpful because it 1) solves the initial problem in an easy to understand way and 2) gives the asker a new tool for their proverbial toolbelt.

Comment: I have to agree, this is way better than trying to use alias

Comment: Ironically I asked this question specifically looking for an alternative to the accepted answer knowing angels like you do exist! Thanks for reminding me why I always use to do this <3

Answer (score 14):

Since [Bash 2.04](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/bashchanges) there is a third (easier) way beside using a function or escaping [the way @ffledgling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20111180/4970442) did: using string literal syntax ([here is an excellent answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30904/209677)).

So for example if you want to make an alias of [this onliner](https://askubuntu.com/a/1130144/349837) it will end up being:

```
alias snap-removedisabled=$'snap list --all | awk \'$5~"disabled"{print $1" --revision "$3}\' | xargs -rn3 snap remove'
```

So you just have to add the `$` in front of the string and escape the single quotes.

This brings [a shellcheck warning](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2139) you could probably safely disable [with `# shellcheck disable=SC2139`](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/Ignore).

Answer (score 3):

You can revert the double and simple quotations, so that **double quotations are outside of single quotations**.

For example, this does not work:

```sh
alias docker-table='docker ps --format "table {{.ID}}\t{{.Image}}\t{{.Status}}"'
```

But this works:

```sh
alias docker-table="docker ps --format 'table {{.ID}}\t{{.Image}}\t{{.Status}}'"
```

And when you check the actual alias interpreted, you can see the inner quotations are actually escaped.

```
$ alias docker-table
alias docker-table='docker ps --format '\''table {{.ID}}\t{{.Image}}\t{{.Status}}'\'''
```

Comment: The other solutions were not working for me.. But this worked.. Thanks..