# bash - how is * interpreted in aliases?

Tags: bash

[Note - I solved the problem I ran into using a bash function, but I want to understand why my initial attempt didn't work.]

I run git in Windows, and use the Git Bash command line application to manage repositories.
I have several repositories that I often want to pull all at once. Previously I was doing this just by entering the following on the command line:

```
for i in *; do cd $i; git pull --rebase; cd ..; done;
```

To save time, I decided to create an alias for this. So, I created a .bashrc file in the home directory (C:/git in my case) and added the line

```
alias pr="for i in *; do cd $i; git pull --rebase; cd ..; done;"
```

However, this didn't work at all, the output was

```
sh.exe" cd: /etc/profile.d/*.sh: No such file or directory
```

followed by git complaining that it wasn't in a repository. The output would be repeated over 20 times for a single call. The root of the MinGW filesystem, where the /etc above derives from, is where I installed git to (C:/Program Files (x86)/Git).

Now, I solved this problem in the end by creating a function in my .bashrc file instead, like so:

```
pr(){
    for i in *
    do
        cd $i
        git pull --rebase
        cd ..
    done
}
```

So, my problem is solved, but I do want to understand why my initial approach didn't work. There's clearly something about aliases I don't understand that is, presumably, mangling the 'i in *' bit. My expectation was that bash would substitute the string the alias maps to and then evaluate it, but it doesn't seem to be that straightforward.

Comment: What happens if you add `echo "i=$i"` right before the `pr` alias assignment and re-source?

Comment: Also, you probably want to make it short-circuit conditional `cd "$i" && git pull --rebase && cd ..`. Otherwise you could get some weird results (`$i` is not a directory, but you still run `git` and move up a level, etc...)

Comment: possible duplicate of [bash alias command with both single and double quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20111063/bash-alias-command-with-both-single-and-double-quotes)

Comment: @BroSlow - just like the answer below, you put me on the right path with your `echo` suggestion. Thanks for the `&&` suggestion, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't analyzed this in full, but it has to do with the time at which your `$i` in the alias gets expanded. The way you're doing this, `$i` will probably be initialized during alias creation. In the function version, it will be interpreted at run-time. Try defining the alias as you've shown, then run:

```
alias pr  # show how the alias is defined
```

Bash will happily postpone expansion of `$`-variables if you define the alias with single quotes. The following should work as well as your function.

```
alias pr='for i in *; do cd $i; git pull --rebase; cd ..; done;'
```

Comment: Someone, please explain the `-1`

Comment: +1 This is absolutely correct; the `$i` inside the double quotes was expanded before the alias was defined. Parameter expansion is not performed inside single quotes or (as the OP discovered) in the body of a function when the function is defined.

Comment: Aha, it seems you're right. `alias pr` gives the following output:

`alias pr='for i in *; do cd /etc/profile.d/*.sh; git pull --rebase; cd ..; done;'`

So it's a problem with `$i` being expanded and not, as I thought, something to do with `*`.

I've verified that it does work with single quotes, too.