# .bashrc command to copy current working directory

Tags: bash, escaping, alias

I am trying to write an alias for the following command that takes your current working directory, surrounded by quotes, and copies it to the clipboard.

```
echo \"$(pwd)\" | xclip
```

However, writing an alias for this in `.bashrc` is not working quite right. This is the alias I have written:

```
alias cpwd="echo \"\$(pwd)\" | xclip"
```

But when that command is ran the double quotes are omitted. I have checked answers to similar problems, such as [bash alias command with both single and double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20111063/bash-alias-command-with-both-single-and-double-quotes), but I think I am escaping all the required characters, so I do not know why this command isn't working.

The current result of the command would be something like: `home/user/My Folder` rather than `"home/user/My Folder"` like I am wanting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need more escaping. You've correctly escaped the `$`; you need to do the same with the existing backslashes.

```
alias cpwd="echo \\"\$(pwd)\\" | xclip"
```

Alternatively, you can avoid all the escaping by using single quotes.

```
alias cpwd='echo \"$(pwd)\" | xclip'
```

Best of all, use a function instead of an alias. A function lets you write the command exactly as you would normally without *any* extra quotes or escaping.

```
cpwd() {
    echo \"$(pwd)\" | xclip
}
```