# How can I mark externally deleted files for Subversion deletion?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We use Subversion for version control on a project.

I have a process separate from Subversion that "cleans up" my working copy of the repository by deleting some files that are no longer needed. I would like to mark the deleted files in a script file as deleted for Subversion, so that on my next commit with Tortoise SVN the deletions are automatically selected instead of just being marked as "missing".

A similar question was asked in [svn delete removed files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066296/svn-delete-removed-files), but the answers proposed there do not work. They suggest using the command

```
svn delete filename.txt
```

When `filename.txt` has already been deleted, I get an error message:

```
svn: E200005: Use --force to override this restriction (local modifications may be lost)
svn: E200005: 'C:\filename.txt' is not under version control
```

If I use the `--force` option, I still get an error message:

```
svn: E125001: 'C:\filename.txt' does not exist
```

One of the reasons for using the external clean-up routine is that some of the files are *.dll's that may currently be in use. Windows prevents their deletion in that case. Only after successful deletion do I want to mark the deletion for a Subversion commit.

If I do

```
svn delete --force filename.dll
```

directly, when the file is still in use Subversion marks the file for deletion but can't actually delete it and the result is a Subversion data inconsistency that even the Subversion cleanup command can't easily solve.

Therefore my question:

How can I mark an already deleted file for Subversion deletion, using the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the question 100% but a poorman's approach could be

svn delete --quiet filename.dll

Comment: Why do you think this solves the problem? What happens when you execute that command? It helps when you add a little bit more information to you answer

Comment: This command also leads to an error: `svn: E200005: Use --force to override this restriction (local modifications may be lost)
svn: E200005: 'C:\filename.txt' is not under version control`. Note that `filename.txt` has already been deleted. I'm looking for a way to tell Subversion with a command line operation that the deletion was intentional and should be committed to the repository.