# Commit svn command with all files checked

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm looking for a parameter of the commit command to send all files (modified, deleted, versioned, etc...).
For example, I have a file that was deleted, when I execute the command "commit PATH -m "Commit of %date%" "
nothing happened because the file is unceck when we try to commit manually...

Is there a solution for me ?

I tried arguments of commit command like --no-unlock --target etc...

Comment: When you just delete a file that file is not deleted by svn standards. It's "[missing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25492747/395718)" instead.

Comment: Sure, but how to commit this missing file like a deleted file ?

It's possible when we commit manualy to include missing files but how to do that with command ?

Comment: Follow the link I provided, and maybe you will find a satisfactory answer. There is no one command from svn. Svn does not care. You have to make a script, and then call it.