# Batch File | Sync up between two SVN repository using batch command

Tags: svn, batch-file, synchronization

Here, I am trying to migrate the SVN TRUNK with Branch code base.

I used For F to remove the data from SVN trunk using Filelist.txt. but it is throwing error.

Here is my cmd:

1st try

```
for /F "tokens=*" %i in (%deleteFileListDir%\Filelist.txt) do ( svn delete "%%i" %svncredentials% )
```

Error: %%i was unexpected at this time.

2nd Try-

```
for /F "tokens=*" %i in (%deleteFileListDir%\Filelist.txt) do ( svn delete "%i" %svncredentials% )
```

Error:

```
\scripts>(svn delete "D:\..\..\reports\" --username abcd--password xyz@999
: Error resolving case of 'D:\..\..\reports" --username abcd --password xyz'
```

I cannot see what I am missing from for /f syntax.
Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That you want to get - in plain words?!

Comment: Here, I am able to migrate data from Branch to trunk,
1. Filelist show list of files which are extra in trunk.
2. while executing delete command (i.e. deleting extra files from trunk which is not present in Branch), i am getting above 2 errors.

Comment: Still can't see **business-task** here - migrating data in (any) SCM is merging

Comment: Although it does not seems making sense to me to do branch merging in such way, you may see if this is your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137219/aptana-1-5-svn-error-resolving-case-of

Answer (score 0):

In your first try, you have "for..**%i**...**%%i**..."

Directly from the prompt, you need to use `%i` to access the metavariable. If this is a line within a batch file, you need `%%i`.

The second error message is from `svn`, not `cmd`. Unfortunately, you seem to have censored it too heavily for it to make much sense. It may mean that it's objecting because there is a mismatch in the case of the string "%%i" (obtained from the file) and the target data. It could also mean that "in the case (ie. instance) "%%i" (derived from the file) - SVN has encountered some problem in resolving what to do".